# IIS7 HTTP Redirect - how to drop/ignore the original's relative path?

Tags: redirect, iis, iis-7

Using IIS7's built in "HTTP Redirect" for a site.

**Problem**

- Entering: `original.com/abc/efg`
- Gives: `redirect.com/abc/efg` - which is not a page on the `redirect` destination!

**I want**

- Entering: `original.com/abc/efg`
- Gives: `redirect.com`

*I already `Checked` "Redirect all requests to exact destination"*

---

Note - while `original.com/abc/efg` does NOT give `redirect.com`...

`original.com/abc/efg/` (include ending slash) *DOES* give `redirect.com`. Bug with IIS7 HTTP Redirect?

Comment: Could you share your url rewrite rule?

Comment: It's not thru the URL Rewrite module, it's thru "HTTP Redirect" (I guess no one really uses that, and I shouldn't?) I'll see if I can upload a photo

Comment: you could upload the image on this site and share image.[link](https://imgur.com/upload)